# Microsoft Server 2016 Hyper-V/converged Switch issue

Tags: networking, windows-server-2016, hyper-v-manager

I have a Server 2016 Datacenter edition, with Hyper-V installed, on a physical Host.

I created a Virtual Host on the Physical host, then shared the virtualization extensions with it, and installed Hyper-V on it in order to create a virtual host.
I created 2 VM's on the Virtual host. I shut down the firewalls on the VM's for troubleshooting purposes.

All virtual switches, from the physical host on up, are set to External, and have the check mark to "allow management operating system to share this network adapter"

Here is my issue:

- The physical host can ping the virtual host, but **not** the VM's within the virtual host.
- The virtual host can ping **both** the physical host, **and** the VM's running within it.
- The VM's running on the virtual host, can ping each other, and the host they are running on, but NOT the outside of it.

I need the VM's to be able to reach the domain controller that is running on the physical host.

Answer (score 0):

Have you disable your firewall in your physical host?

Have you enable mac spoofing in your vm?

More info

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/user-guide/nested-virtualization

Best Regards,

Frank